# Why is $\alpha$, a primitive pth root of unity, a root of the polynomial $1+t+\ldots +t^{p-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-writing, galois-theory, primitive-roots

I'm currently reading a proof that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, a primitive pth root of unity, over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $$1+t+\ldots +t^{p-1},$$ yet the author simply states "Clearly $\alpha$ is a zero." in the proof, and I can't seem to prove that bit myself.

Comment: Oh, now I see that if I multiply the polynomial by $(t-1)$ I get $t^p-1$, which zeroes are clearly $1, \alpha , \ldots , \alpha ^{p-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $(1+t+\cdots + t^{p-1} ) (1-t)= t^p -1$, and that $\alpha$ is a root of $t^p -1$, since it is a pth root of unity, but not of $1-t$, since it is primitive. Then it must be a root of $1+\cdots+t^{p-1}$, as the author says.